# Tax refund in stores that are not close to the border

Tags: air-travel, switzerland, austria, tax-refunds

I'm living in a border region, and every time I'm shopping abroad, I can fill out a form at the store, let the border officer sign it, go back to the store and get the sales tax back.

Now I'm traveling to the same country, but this time I'm going to a region that is not close to the border. So I'm asking myself what the procedure should be. Do the stores also have these forms? Where can I get the signature of a border officer at the airport?

Comment: That depends. Which is the country you're going to, and from?  I see you've tagged it as [tag:switzerland] and [tag:austria] but they may have different rules?

Comment: I'm talking about shopping in Austria and entering into Switzerland.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Can you share your experiences if you have done the same thing recently? I'm planning to buy some jewelry in Salzburg but will be flying back home from Zurich. If necessary, we could detour to German border to get form stamped and then go back to the store before heading back to Switzerland.

Comment: [Found my answer](https://www.bmeia.gv.at/en/austrian-consulate-general-los-angeles/travels-to-austria/vat-refund/) - I need to find customs at a border crossing since I'm driving rather than flying. `When leaving Austria to Switzerland and Liechtenstein, you must obtain your customs stamp from Austrian customs officials either at the airport or the border crossing.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elsewhere I've traveled the stores carrying the Tax Refund forms are hit and miss.  The larger stores that get a lot of tourist traffic would have the forms on hand but the smaller ones are a hit and miss.

Normally the signature of a Border Control officer is not required since most places the refund is given at the airport.

For Example [Tel-Aviv Airport](http://www.iaa.gov.il/Rashat/en-US/Airports/BenGurion/InformationforTravelers/Services/Currency/VATRefund/TaxRefund.htm) has 2 locations where you get your refund and all you need is a check and form, which you can obtain at any store or at the VAT refund counter itself.

In Canada at the land border crossings the Tax Refund was given at the Duty Free Shops like [IGL](http://www.dutyfreecanada.com/stores/igl-duty-free-shop/) and the form to claim the refund can be [obtained online](http://www.hillsporthillton.com/gstrebateform.pdf).

Europe on the other hand may be different.  But in Austria for example you can follow this site to find where the [locations for refund are](http://www.taxfreeworldwide.com/images/pdf/at_refund%20points_austria.pdf) and the same one in [Switzerland](http://www.taxfreeworldwide.com/images/pdf/at_refund%20points_switzerland.pdf).

**EDIT**

Additional Information about [VAT refunds from Zurich airport](http://www.zurich-airport.com/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-163/).  You can take a look at the map for where the [Customs are located](http://www.zurich-airport.com/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-163/436_read-1288/).  One thing they might be asking from you though would probably be a boarding pass, so I don't know how you would be able to get back to the store afterwards.

Comment: I know that the are some refund places at borders or airports. But in my experience, the problem is that they keep around 10% of your money. If you go directly back to the store, you get the full amount.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Not everywhere but if I recall correctly in Germany out of 20% VAT(old data) you can only get back 12%(which is what I was told at the store).  Same in Canada you can only get back GST and not PST, etc.  In Tel-Aviv I didn't get back only stuff lost in currency exchange (yeah rates are not the best but not terrible).  And BTW stores there wouldn't give you back taxes even if you provide them a signed form.

Comment: Maybe that's correct, but I'm not interested in Germany, Canada or Israel.